# Split a column of character vectors and return a list

Tags: r, split, character, unique

I have the following *dataframe*:

```
df <- data.frame(Sl.No = c(1:6),
                 Variable = c('a', 'a,b', 'a,b,c', 'b', 'c', 'b,c'))


   Sl.No   Variable
   1         a
   2         a,b
   3         a,b,c
   4         b
   5         c
   6         b,c
```

I want to separate the unique values in the variable column as list

```
myList <- ("a", "b", "c")
```

I have tried the following code:

```
separator <- function(x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]][[1]]
unique(sapply(df$Variable, separator))
```

This however gives me the following output:

```
"a"
```

I request some help. I have searched but seem unable to find an answer to this.

Comment: Perfect. Works neatly. Unique values obtained after unlisting list obtained by stringsplit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the `Variable` column at "," and get all the values and select only the `unique` ones.

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(df$Variable, ",")))
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

If the `Variable` column is factor convert it into character before using `strsplit`.